# On migrating to unix-SE

Tags: discussion, migration

[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) has recently been launched, so I'm wondering if there are questions in here that need migrating.

The [FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq) states that this site is not for *General personal computer troubleshooting*. Now since both SU and unix.SE have massive overlap, the question is more of which of the two sites to migrate to? I prefer they be migrated to Unix & Linux, but that's another argument.

- [*nix measure memory usage](https://serverfault.com/questions/99023/nix-measure-memory-usage)
- [Linux command line best practices and tips?](https://serverfault.com/questions/68883/linux-command-line-best-practices-and-tips)
- [What useful things can one add to one's .bashrc?](https://serverfault.com/questions/3743/what-useful-things-can-one-add-to-ones-bashrc)
- [Hidden Features of Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/2817/hidden-features-of-linux)
- [Why do I have to edit /etc/sudoers with visudo?](https://serverfault.com/questions/26303/why-do-i-have-to-edit-etc-sudoers-with-visudo)
- [Why su to root instead of logging in as root?](https://serverfault.com/questions/41841/why-su-to-root-instead-of-logging-in-as-root)
- [What's the difference between apt-get and aptitude?](https://serverfault.com/questions/21105/whats-the-difference-between-apt-get-and-aptitude)
- [Do I need to defrag unix filesystems?](https://serverfault.com/questions/782/do-i-need-to-defrag-linux-filesystems)
- [What is the difference between a 'Login' and an 'Interactive' bash shell](https://serverfault.com/questions/8882/what-is-the-difference-between-a-login-and-an-interactive-bash-shell)

Comment: The FAQ says this site is for professionals only. Putting "sez" in your question is worse that fingernails on a chalkboard. I stopped reading your update right there.

Comment: @chris can u remove the downvote; someone edited it to look *more professional*

Comment: @Tshepang, votes don't affect reputation on meta.SF

Comment: I edited the post to include the relevant questions, since that makes it a heck of a lot more readable -- please avoid putting lots of links in comments.

Comment: @Jeff Ok, will avoid that. Note that that's not a comprehensive list, just stuff I got on the first page of [linux] tag.

Comment: @Chris I'm not concerned about rep in this case. Your reason for downvoting was "sez", and that means that you should remove your vote if that's fixed.

Comment: Using "u" instead of "you" is just as bad as "sez".

Comment: @john Wow! So I can't go 'unprofessional' even on comments!

Comment: @Tshepang, you might also like to think about your incorrect and excessive use of exclamation marks.

Comment: Note also that `.se` is a valid top-level domain name, and in fact  http://unix.se/ appears to be a completely valid and functional web site. Please don't use *.se (even with capitalized SE) as nicknames for stack exchange sites.

Comment: @mattdm Someone suggested unix-SE. I think it's a great idea.

Comment: @Tshepang — agreed.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a migration path that will be unlocked.

Both "flavors" of Unix questions can survive -- those directed towards sysadmins, and those directed torwards a general audience of Unix users and distributions.

Comment: You have a tendency to just say __no__ without an explanation. Why do you wanna keep the generic questions here?

Comment: @tshe the explanation is there, you just don't like it.

Comment: @Tshepang, the explination is there are two different types of questions related to *nix platforms, general usage and system administration. Cross-Posting is discouraged, but a question that is appropriate for both can be posted on either (and is likely to get an adequate response). The Unix & Linux site is more closely related to SuperUser anyway.

Comment: @chris I know that with current policy, those questions are as equally valid on SU as on unix.SE. So I guess the argument can change to which to migrate to? It's pretty clear that they don't fit here, since they are general usage. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you **really** feel that a question will be better off on the Unix & Linux site then flag the post for moderator attention and explain why.

They have access to a "migrate anywhere" option which isn't bound by the normal close to migrate dialog.

However, I would wait for a moderator to answer whether they'd be happy with this before flagging *any* questions.